# PHP 7.1 `session_write_close()` returns `null` but manual consist of `bool`

Tags: php, function, session, types, return

As mentioned in the PHP manual

[PHP Manual :: session_write_close() :: Return Values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php#refsect1-function.session-write-close-returnvalues)

I expected a boolean return value which I'd like to return from my wrapping method. Now I got the error that null has been returned.

While searching I didn't find any glues someone else ran into this issue.

Please, could anyone explain this?

---

**Edit (2018-02-15 18:26)**

```
public function writeClose(): bool
{
    return session_write_close(); // returns void(?)
}
```

Comment: May be dumb, but does your wrapper call `return session_write_close();` or just `session_write_close();`?

Comment: `return session_write_close()` Using PHPStorm I already get a hint the return type would be `void` while I'm expecting `bool`. That's quiet confusing.

Comment: @codekandis Including your actual code in the question would be helpful.

Comment: @codekandis: I get `NULL` also on PHP 7.0.26, I guess it could be an error in the docs, which you could report to their issue tracker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [has been fixed](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/7f196e321) in 7.2. See also https://3v4l.org/2Y5q9.